# How to express probabilities as a function of another inside pdf?

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

It's not really a problem, but I wonder how to express an expression (sorry for such a poor language) inside pdf system as a function of another? For example we have pdf is
$$\begin{cases}
a&0\le x\le0.5\\
b&0.5<x\le1\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Is there any chance to express $b$ in terms of $a$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel You´re not right. See the answer of FullofDill.

Comment: @callculus You're not right; what if the support includes values outside $[0,1]$? Not covered by the given answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I interprete the answer in the way that $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $x>1$. With that conditional yes the questions can be answered.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  that's probably my fault for not including this, but my teacher told us to assume that outside this interval p=0

Comment: @callculus And _then_ the given answer is right.

Comment: I thought, clearly wrongly, @Alice was asking about the general case, and the given piecewise constant pdf was just a clarifying example

Comment: If the support extended to $\pm \infty$ then you couldn't have the sort of pdf she is describing because it wouldn't integrate to 1. The "general" case is not a pdf.

Comment: @FullofDill, I was certainly not referring to the possibility you mention. I was referring to the case whereby $a$ and $b$ are functions, not constants.

Comment: @An aedonist I see what you mean. I think it's best to answer the simple case she provided and then continue the discussion if it's not sufficient for her "real" question. The original commenter simply saying "No" and then getting defensive and pedantic doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $f(x)$ is your pdf, you can write this:

$$1 = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \int_0^{0.5} a\,dx + \int_{0.5}^1 b\,dx = 0.5a + 0.5b \implies b = 2 -a$$

Comment: Its genius, thx